# Try Catch Exceptions of the Same Type Java

Tags: java, exception, try-catch

I want to know if there is a way to have the same exception type in a catch.

So basically we have this:

```
catch(IllegalArgumentException exception){
  throw new IllegalArgumentException("Error CheckingAccount: negative initial balance");
  throw new IllegalArgumentException("Error deposit: negative amount");
  throw new IllegalArgumentException("Error withdraw: illegal amount");
}
```

I was wondering how it can change between the same exception type but have it be called when it is needed. Do I need `if-else` statements? By the way this is not in main.

To be specific this is `String getMessage()`.

Comment: I don't fully follow your problem.  Typically, you would catch and rethrow because you want to do some intermediate error handling, e.g. writing to an error log.  What are you trying to do here?

Comment: So for example we have a bank account class. And the tester puts in a negative balance. So then we have it output "Error CheckingAccount: negative initial balance." I am wondering if the person wanted to deposit in money and it is a negative amount how it would not use the exception.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You don't *shuffle*.

Your method simply does multiple checks, and throws the same kind of exception but with different messages.

And your code that calls this method has one catch for this type of exception and prints the message.

That is all there is to this.

Comment: How would I change what goes out when it is needed?

Comment: Again : multiple if statements that do some kind of check and each do a throw with a different message.

Answer (score 0):

According to the your code always throw the first one inside the catch clause.
You can define your own exception class and throw all exceptions to it. Then you can log your errors by using Loggers.

```
catch(IllegalArgumentException exception){
        throw new MyExceptionClass(exception.getMessage(),exception);
```

}

your class can be like this:

```
public class MyExceptionClass extends Exception {
/**
 * @param messages
 * @param e
 */
public MyExceptionClass (String messages,Exception e   ){
    super(messages,e);
}
```

}

Answer (score 0):

For different type of scenarios, you can create different type of user defined exceptions.

In your case, you can defined three new exceptions like this:

```
class NegativeInitialBalance extends Exception {}
class NegativeAmount extends Exception {}
class IllegalAmount extends Exception {}
```

*Just declaring the class would be enough if you don't want any detailing*

Now you can throw these exceptions from your class and catch them appropriately. Then you can rethrow them with appropriate message, for example

```
try {

    if(initialBalance < 0) {
        throw new NegativeInitialBalance();
    }
    ..
     if (amount < 0) {
        thrwo new NegativeAmount();
    }
    ...
    if(amount > limit) {
        throw new IllegalAmount();
    }


}
catch (NegativeInitialBalance e) {
    throw new IllegalArgumentException("Error CheckingAccount: negative initial balance");
}
catch (NegativeAmount e) {
    throw new IllegalArgumentException("Error deposit: negative amount");
}
catch (IllegalAmount e) {
    throw new IllegalArgumentException("Error withdraw: illegal amount");
}
```

---

**EDIT**

A better approach would be to use your custom exceptions instead of rethrowing them with `IllegalArgumentException` message. You can define your exceptions like this.

```
class NegativeInitialBalance extends Exception {
    @Override
    public String toString() { 
        return ("Error CheckingAccount: negative initial balance");
    }
}

class NegativeAmount extends Exception {
    @Override
    public String toString() { 
        return ("Error deposit: negative amount");
    }
}

class IllegalAmount extends Exception {
    @Override
    public String toString() { 
        return ("Error withdraw: illegal amount");
    }
}
```

no need to catch and rethrow them again. directly use them

```
public static void main(String[] args) {

    ...

    if(initialBalance < 0) {
        throw new NegativeInitialBalance();
    }
    ..
     if (amount < 0) {
        thrwo new NegativeAmount();
    }
    ...
    if(amount > limit) {
        throw new IllegalAmount();
    }

}
```

Comment: Nice example but misleading. You either really throw the different special exceptions to the user, or you don't use them. There is no point in inventing custom exceptions to then hide them this way!

Comment: @GhostCat I agree. The better option would be to use these exceptions only instead of rethrowing them. Have edited answer accordingly.

Answer (score 0):

You'll need an if-else to choose between then.

```
double div(double d1, double d2){
    if(d2 == 0)
        throw new IllegalArgumentException("Division by 0.");
    if(d2 > d1)
       throw new IllegalArgumentException("Some message.");
    if(something else)
       throw new IllegalArgumentException("Your message.");
    return d1/d2;
}
```

You can also use try-catch as well.

```
double div(Double d1, Double d2){
    try{
        return d1/d2;
    }catch(ArithmeticException e){
        throw new ArithmeticException("Division by 0");
    }catch(NullPointerException e2){
        throw e2;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Create enum with all possible Argument exceptions:

```
enum ArgumentExceptions {
    NEGATIVE_INITIAL_BALANCE("Error CheckingAccount: negative initial balance"),
    NEGATIVE_DEPOSIT("Error deposit: negative amount"),
    ILLEGAL_WITHDRAW("Error withdraw: illegal amount");

    private String value;

    ArgumentExceptions(String value) {
        this.value = value;
    }

    public String getValue() {
        return value;
    }
}
```

Then create method

```
private void assertTrue(boolean condition, ArgumentExceptions exception) {
    if (!condition) {
        throw new IllegalArgumentException(exception.getValue());
    }
}
```

Then you can use it:

```
public void someMethod() {
    int initialBalance = -2;
    int amount = 3;
    int withdraw = 5;

    assertTrue(initialBalance < 0, ArgumentExceptions.NEGATIVE_INITIAL_BALANCE);
    assertTrue(amount < 0, ArgumentExceptions.NEGATIVE_DEPOSIT);
    assertTrue(withdraw < 0, ArgumentExceptions.ILLEGAL_WITHDRAW);
}
```

Of course types of variables can be different (I suggest to use BigDecimal for balance).